# How do I compare the variables held within two objects before returning them from an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have a class, `FlightDatabase` which contains a number of `AirJourney` objects, these air journey objects have the following details: Origin airport, destination airport and number of miles in flight.

For example one `AirJourney` object may have Origin: A, Destination: B and miles: 400.

The following array of strings represents each `AirJourney` object present in the database, with the first letter being the origin, the second the destination and the third the number of miles in the flight.

`"AB800", "BC900", "CD400", "DE400", "BF400", "CE300", "DE300", "EB600", "CE200", "DC700", "EB500", "FD200"`

Within this string there are a number of repeated flights: `DE400` and `DE300` and then `CE300` and `CE200`.

I need to be able to return `AirJourney` objects from the `FlightDatabase` and also ignore any flights that are of a higher number of miles.

The method below allows the returning of AirJourney objects from the database by using a string consisting of two letters that will match with the origin and destination airports held within the object. However this method will return the first matching object, not the one of the fewest amount of miles.

```
public AirJourney getFlightDetailsFromAirportPairing(String airportPair)
    {
        for(AirJourney journey : database)
        {
            String journeyPair = journey.getOriginAirport() + journey.getDestinationAirport();
            if(airportPair.equals(journeyPair))
            {
                return journey;
            }
        }

        return new AirJourney(0, null, null);
    }
```

For example if I call `getFlightDetailsFromAirportPairing("DE") then the DE400 flight will be returned, when instead I want the DE300 flight to be returned and the DE400 flight is to be ignored.

I am not sure how to modify this method so that it will return the flight of the lowest amount of miles.

Comment: You can create a variable which will store lowest met journey, that fits airportPair string. Instead returning journey immediatelly, loop through whole database, compare with journey kept in variable and replace if new journey has lower length

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this can be used?

The idea is to store the lowest value seen, and whenever you see something with a lower value, you store the AirJourney object and the distance.

```
public AirJourney getFlightDetailsFromAirportPairing(String airportPair){
        double lowestDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        AirJourney lowestDistanceAirJourney = null;
        for (AirJourney journey : database) {
            String journeyPair = journey.getOriginAirport() + journey.getDestinationAirport();
            if(airportPair.equals(journeyPair)) {
                if (lowestDistanceAirJourney == null || journey.getMiles() < lowestDistance) {
                    lowestDistanceAirJourney = journey;
                    lowestDistance = journey.getMiles();
                }
            }
        }
        return lowestDistanceAirJourney;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public AirJourney getFlightDetailsFromAirportPairing(String airportPair)
{
    Journey matchJourney = new AirJourney(0, null, null);
    for(AirJourney journey : database)
    {
        String journeyPair = journey.getOriginAirport() + journey.getDestinationAirport();
        if(airportPair.equals(journeyPair))
        {
            if(matchJourney.getMileage() == 0)
            {
                matchJourney = journey;
            }
            else if(journey.getMileage() < matchJourney.getMileage()
            {
                matchJourney = journey;
            }
        }
    }

    return matchJourney;
}
```

Loop through every journey and add a check for the mileage.

Answer (score 0):

use below method using java 8 streams and it might help you :

```
    public static String getFlightDetailsFromAirportPairing(String airportPair) {
            List<String> database = Arrays.asList("DE400", "DE300");  // you can get it from your database
            String journeyPair = "DE"; // you can get it from your database
            int minimumMiles = database.stream().map(value -> Integer.valueOf(value.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)")[1])).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().reduce((x, y) -> x.compareTo(y) <= 0  ? x : y).get();
            if (airportPair.equals(journeyPair) ) {
                return journeyPair + minimumMiles;
            } else {
                return null;
            }           
}
```

For your minimumMiles from journey you can use :

```
int minimumMiles = database.stream().map(journey -> journey.getMiles()).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().reduce((x, y) -> x.compareTo(y) <= 0  ? x : y).get();
```

I am assuming that getMiles() is returning integer , if it is not then you have to use `Integer.valueOf(journey.getMiles())`
It will get minimum miles for a airportPair and then will give the result.

Please do let me know if that worked for you or not.